# Get interim results of function calls while debugging Python in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, chain

On breakpoints --> **PyCharm debugger** shows current list of variable states *and* is also able to show previous lines calculation/call results.

But what if I want to get interim results on function chain calls at the same line of code?

For example:

```py
l = [3, 4, 5]
l = list(map(str, l)) #here I want to check result "of map(str, l)"

s = "_".join(l).upper()[::-1] #here I want see values for each interim func calls (join, upper)
```

Is it somehow possible in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using a breakpoint on that line. Right click on the breakpoint and use a tuple in the `Evalute and log` field having as values the incremental method chain calls:

The following code shows differences in intermediate results:

```py
l = ['Hello', 'my', 'friends']

s = "_".join(l).upper()[::-1]
```

Using a tuple in `Evaluate and log`:

```py
(l, "_".join(l), "_".join(l).upper(), "_".join(l).upper()[::-1])
```

The debugger shows the results on standard output:

```
(['Hello', 'my', 'friends'], 'Hello_my_friends', 'HELLO_MY_FRIENDS', 'SDNEIRF_YM_OLLEH')
```

Corresponding screenshot:

[image]